# Is constructor use allowed with case classes?

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

I have a case class (let's name it `Stuff`) that I want to be able to create anonymous subclasses of at run time by extending a trait (call it `Marker`). Here's a snippet of a REPL session that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
scala> trait Marker
defined trait Marker

scala> case class Stuff(i: Int)
defined class Stuff

scala> val a = Stuff(1)
a: Stuff = Stuff(1)

scala> val b = new Stuff(1) with Marker
b: Stuff with Marker = Stuff(1)
```

Note how `a` is instantiated using `Stuff.apply()`, while in `b`'s case I'm calling the case class' constructor.

My question is: **is instantiating case classes using a constructor kosher?** It appears to me that it is, since the usual conveniences provided by case classes, such as `==`, `.equals()`, and `.hashCode()`, all work. Am I missing anything that would brand what I'm doing a *Bad Thing (TM)*?

```
scala> a == b
res0: Boolean = true

scala> a.equals(b)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> a.hashCode == b.hashCode
res2: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how `Stuff.apply` is implemented:

```
object Stuff {
  def apply(i: Int): Stuff = new Stuff(i)
}
```

So there's no harm at all in using `new Stuff`.

Answer (score 3):

To the question

> is instantiating case classes using a constructor kosher

the answer is definitely yes. Something like

```
val b = new Stuff(1)
```

poses no problems at all. Now, `new Stuff(1) with Marker` is different because an anonymous subclass of `Stuff` is created. I believe, though, that it's still unproblematic. The problems I know about appear when **case classes** inherit from other case classes, and you aren't doing that. But I may be unaware of something.

EDIT: just tested matching in the REPL:

```
scala> val b = new Stuff(1)
b: Stuff = Stuff(1)

scala> b match {case Stuff(x) => x}
res0: Int = 1

scala> b match {case Stuff(_) => true}
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: The only potential minor issue I see there is with pattern matching. `b` above will not match against Stuff(_), but `val c: Stuff = new Stuff(1) with Marker` will match just fine.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thought "`b` above" referred to the `b` in my reply.